# How to add walls or other solid obejcts to Eulers equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, boundary-conditions

I've recently started learning about the physics of fluids and I've found that euler's equations exist and that I can use them to compute the flow of fluids with zero viscosity. But I have a problem that I don't see any easy way of adding an obstacle to a compessible flow as shown in this gif

[image]

How should I do it? Is something similar possible also with navier-stokes equations? 
(I am aware that this questions is probably a duplicate of some older question, because this sounds as a really basic problem, but I've search for the anwer for some time and I even asked on the physics discord server and I found nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add anything to the Euler or Navier-Stokes *equations*. To solve the equations you need boundary conditions. The walls appear in those.

Comment: I found, that the boundary condition is n . u = 0 for euler's equations, but the source of this info didn't state where it is true. Is it only on the boundary or in the whole volume of the fluid? (I guess that it's the first option, but it confused me a little bit because when I looked at navier stokes equations, the same source stated that it is only on the boundary)

Comment: "Boundary conditions" are conditions that apply on the boundary.

Comment: Your boundary condition is primarily that the normal and tangential velocities (i.e. all velocity components) are zero at the walls of your airfoil.